# How to show a within-group continuous data but compare between groups

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a dataframe called ret1 as follows:

```
 chr    binRight    Means
 chr1   1.20e+07    25.320212
 chr1   2.40e+07    30.875749
 chr2   1.60e+07    48.952099
 chr2   2.80e+07    41.356140
 chr2   6.00e+07    20.078314
 chr3   2.20e+07    37.107468
 chr3   3.40e+07    38.257566
 chr3   9.60e+07    38.381219
 chr3   1.08e+08    30.218046
```

I would like to create a histogram that plots the Means column as a continuous plot grouped by chr so that I can see for example each Mean for each binRight for chr1 and then each mean for each binRight for chr2 etc on the same axis.

Ideally I'd like this to look like a kind of graphics equaliser histogram if anyone knows how to do that as well.

I tried

```
p = ggplot(ret1, aes(x=ret1$binRight)) + geom_histogram(ret1$Means) +
p + facet_grid(chr ~ .)
```

but that gives me a count per chr and Mean on the x-axis whereas although I like the look of the plot and the way the chr is seperated I need binRight on the x-axis and the Means as the y axis of the plot.

## Update:

Using what I've learned this should give some nice plots for people out there:

```
#Grouping the data across binRight:
library(dplyr)
ret1 <- df %>%
  group_by(chr, binnum = (leftPos) %/% 12000000) %>%
  summarise(Means = mean(Means)) %>%
  mutate(binRight = (binnum+1) * 12000000) %>%
  select(binRight, Means)

#Convert chr column to numeric by stripping out the "chr"
ret1$chr<-as.numeric(gsub("chr","",ret1$chr))


#Doing the plot
d<- ggplot(ret1, aes(x=as.numeric(binRight),y=as.numeric(Means)),colour=Means) + 
   geom_bar(stat = "identity",aes(fill=Means)) +
  ggtitle("My plot")+
  xlab("Genomic locus") +
  ylab("Raw read counts") +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=10)) +
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=14))+
  theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold", size=20)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0, 80)) +
facet_grid(chr ~ .) 
d +scale_fill_gradient(limits = c(0, 80), low = "green", high = "red").
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
p = ggplot(df, aes(x=binRight)) + geom_histogram(aes(y = Means),stat = "identity")
p + facet_wrap(~chr)
```

[image]

Comment: Lovely. Just what I wanted. I have also embellished the code a bit see above